# on duplicate key update doesnt update rather insert a row

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO min_product ( shopid, productid , outward ) 
SELECT shopid, productid , outward 
FROM main_product 
WHERE shopid= '51' 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE outward  = ( SELECT sum(outward)  
                                         FROM main_product WHERE shopid= '51' )
```

main_product table

```
productid outward shopid
    333      2      44//present
    343      4      44//present
    353      5      44//present
    363      1      44//present
    373      2      44//not present
```

min_product table

```
productid outward shopid

333      1      44
343      1      44
353      1      44
363      1      44
```

---

the problem is that it doesnt update on duplicate row rather a new row is inserted ? what is the problem in the query `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: You probably don't have a unique key defined

Comment: @juergend unique key is `productid`

Comment: @JohnWoo i need to check based on `productid`

Comment: @JohnWoo can u tell me how to update and insert for a unique row for the above tables

Comment: @Aryan can you show me the schema of your tables? `DESC min_product` and `DESC main_product`

Answer (score 0):

If your database allows for the duplicate row to be inserted your table is not defined correct - Update is only performed if a duplicate of a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY is inserted

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: can u tell me how to update and insert for a unique row for the above tables